# Save flask-admin editing history

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm trying implement method that will add to column 'editing-date' the date of editing OF ANOTHER column. Like I'm changing username in a row and simultaneously on 'editing-date' appears something like '23.08.18'. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define `editing_date` in your model as DateTime column.

then you can override the `on_model_change()` method in your modelview class definition. Just place the below in your modelview class

```
from datetime import datetime
on_model_change(form, model, is_created):
    if not is_created: # True if model was created and to False if edited
                       # you only want this to run when model is edited so we are using not operator
        model.edit_date = datetime.utcnow()
```

`on_nodel_view()` performs some actions before a model is created or updated and changes are committed to the database. Use this whenever you want to run extra code before the changes are committed to the database

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me out!

Comment: Awesome! happy I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

In your model define a column like this:

```
    editing_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
```